# VS2019 - Attempting to Publish an SQLCLR Class Library - System.Drawing' is not trusted

Tags: c#

When I attempt to Publish my SQLCLR program, I get the following error:

(47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10327, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'SqlClassLibrary' failed because assembly 'System.Drawing' is not trusted. The assembly is trusted when either of the following is true: the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission, or the assembly is trusted using sp_add_trusted_assembly.

System.Drawing IS in sys.trusted_assemblies. It was added using sp_add_trusted_assembly.

However, VS2019 still seems to think it is not.

permission-set-desc: UNSAFE_ACCESS

Comment: have you seen [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b12abdd8-5185-43c7-8606-a434e4848f97/error-in-create-assembly-in-sql-msg-6285?forum=sqlnetfx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating an Asymmetric key using System.Drawing and a login for it with Unsafe Assembly permissions:

```
USE master; GO CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY SQLCLRTestKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Drawing.dll'; CREATE LOGIN 
SQLCLRTestLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY SQLCLRTestKey ; GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO 
SQLCLRTestLogin ; GO
```